# Can you vote to protect / flag a question for protection?

Tags: support, protected-questions

I don't have enough rep to actually protect or unprotect a question myself but a couple of times I've come across questions that are getting quite a few low rated answers or otherwise poor answers and looked for a way to suggest it be protected.

Does such a method exist? Should I flag it for moderator attention or is that poor use of moderator's time?

I know questions get automatically protected if they meet some criteria so maybe it's just better to ignore it and the system will deal with it (if a high rep user or mod doesn't first)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Flag in need of moderator intervention

Next to the close button, you can vote to flag for moderator attention, then as the note write: this is getting crappy comments and should be protected

## Find a 15k user in chat

Go to our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) and see if you can find a 15k user to protect it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of mentioning it in chat. I'll take either of these actions next time I spot a question that needs it.

Comment: Protecting a question does not affect comments. It only affects the ability of new users on the site to post answers to that one question.