# How to lock my question and/or answers?

Tags: support, questions, answers, moderation

In my personal opinion, *most* of my questions and answers attract *a lot* of comments. Most of the time I am happy about it, sometimes it gives me frustration. Especially having the luck asking the [most voted question on this site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/114033/how-can-santa-keep-his-lists-when-the-gdpr-is-around)

First of all, I am really happy if someone corrects my English grammar and typos *without asking*. I know the feeling, being Czech language Grammar Nazi myself.

Thing is, that some comments are hard to understand on the internet. Was it a joke? Was it a sarcasm? Was it an insult? Even when there is new "[be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)" policy, it is hard to decode for me.

I already asked [how to protect own question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6655/can-you-vote-to-protect-flag-a-question-for-protection) which at least solved not having comments from new users. I thought thats all I can achieve with not having comments, but then I saw this on [Personal finance](https://money.stackexchange.com/) site:

[image: locked answer for comments]

So I *know* it is possible to lock (at least) the answer. Question is: **How to trigger this locking?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Locking can only be done by a moderator, or by the system under certain circumstances. It's not something you can do yourself. A locked post cannot be commented on, voted on, favorited, edited, or answered (if it's a question); basically it shuts down all activity on the post, so this is not something to be done lightly, and in particular not just because you don't want to get comments on it.

If people are *especially* persistent in commenting on your post in an inappropriate way, you can talk to the mods and see if they might be willing to apply a lock, but under normal circumstances, if the comments are inappropriate, it'll probably be better to deal with them using the normal tools, by flagging. Preemptively blocking comments or answers on your question seems to be at odds with the Stack Exchange model, where community feedback is generally encouraged, so I would expect the mods not to want to do it very often.

Locking is explained in more detail [in the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts).

Comment: Flagging comments, though tedious, is actually beneficial.  The system tracks that metric and reacts to it.  Moderators are automatically informed.  If I recall correctly, too many flagged comments can lead to banning.  It's a painfully time-consuming solution, but it's the natural consequence of a system built around the concept of free speech.